# Logging via NLog to AzureBlogStorage for level Info not working

Tags: logging, azure-blob-storage, nlog

I loaded the newest version of NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage
`<PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage" Version="4.2.0" />` in my project in .NET Standard 2.0

Writing logs to my Azure Blob Storage works in my first tests fine but for log level Info. And if I try to write all logs into a single file it's not working.
If I separate the logging into one file per log level it's working for all but `Info`.

[image]

Here is how I configured the logging target:

```
string blobName = $"{this.AzureStorageBlobNamePrefix}_${{shortdate}}_${{level}}.log";
// Azure Blob Storage-Target erstellen
BlobStorageTarget blobStorageTarget = new()
{
    Name = blobStorageTargetName,
    ConnectionString = this.AzureStorageConnectionString,
    Container = this.AzureStorageContainerName,
    BlobName = blobName,
    Layout = layout,
};

// Azure Blob Storage-Target zur LoggingConfiguration hinzufügen
config.AddTarget(blobStorageTargetName, blobStorageTarget);

// Regel erstellen, um das Ziel mit den gewünschten Protokollereignissen zu verknüpfen
var rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, blobStorageTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
```

I tried writing the log into a single file and expected to see the data in there but it stays empty. The same for logging separate into one file per log level at level `Info`.

### Update

The problem seems to occur when I log a more complex string that was produced by a function call.

`logger.Info(GetMyString(p))` is resulting in an empty log.

`logger.Info(() => GetMyString(p))` is working and produces the expected log.

Comment: Maybe just missing to flush. Ex. `NLog.LogManager.Flush()` ?

Comment: Nope. Last line is `NLog.LogManager.Flush();`

Answer (score 0):

Giving you a sample example of how to send logs via NLog to AzureBlogStorage :

```cs
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage;
class Program
{
  static void Main()
    {
       var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        var blobStorageTarget = new BlobStorageTarget
        {
            Name = "sampath123",
            ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol",
            Container = "sam",
            BlobName = "YourBlobName_${shortdate}_${level}.log",
            Layout = "${longdate} ${level} ${message}"
        };
        config.AddTarget(blobStorageTarget);
    var rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, blobStorageTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
      LogManager.Configuration = config;
    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
     logger.Info("Info message");
     logger.Warn("Warning message");
     logger.Error("Error message");
     LogManager.Flush();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you run the program 3 times or did it log your message 3 times in one run? Looks confusing to see 3 entries in the error log file.

Comment: yes i have run 3 times  @Sebastian

Comment: @SPT I am still evaluating if this solution helps. I will close this question if it helps me.

Comment: @Sampath Thanks for the code. I used the example and got closer to the issue. The problem occurs when I log a more complex string that was produced by a function call.  `logger.Info(GetMyString(p))` is resulting in an empty log. `logger.Info(() => GetMyString(p))` is working and produces the expected log.

Comment: It depends on the length of the string to log. In my case the limit is exactly at 639 chars.

If the message to log is 638 characters (or less), the log file will contain the message (like expected).
If the message to log is 639 characters (or more), the log file stays empty.

Comment: I have answer your original question. Please rise a new question for it. I will try to answer it.