# No Logging via NLog to AzureBlogStorage if single message longer than 638 characters

Tags: c#, logging, azure-blob-storage, nlog

I loaded the newest version of NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage
`<PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage" Version="4.2.0" />` in my test project.

Writing logs to my Azure Blob Storage works if it doesn't contain a message longer than 638 chars.
If I write messages containing max. 638 chars it's all working fine. Otherwise it produces an empty file.
[image]

That's the code:

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
var blobStorageTarget = new BlobStorageTarget
{
    Name = blobStorageTargetName,
    ConnectionString = "<my connection string>",
    Container = "myContainer",
    BlobName = $"{prefix}_YourBlobName_${{shortdate}}.log",
    Layout = "${longdate} ${level} ${message}"
};
config.AddTarget(blobStorageTarget);
var rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, blobStorageTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
LogManager.Configuration = config;
var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

logger.Error("now we will soon log the longer String");
string myString = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 639).Select(i => $"a"));

logger.Error(myString );

logger.Trace($"Trace msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");
logger.Debug($"Debug msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");
logger.Info($"Info msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");
logger.Warn($"Warn msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");
logger.Error($"Error msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");

LogManager.Flush();
```

In this case (639 chars) an empty file will be produced. Not even the message before the "long" string is logged. If I reduce myString to 368 chars it's working like expected.

<sup>Background:
This is the question following this one:</sup> <sup>https://stackoverflow.com/q/76581042/12397130</sup>
<sup>I was asked to create a new question even it's the same miss-behaviour.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

***I made some changes with your code and I got the blob with message longer than 638 chars.***

**Code:**

```cs
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;
using NLog.Targets;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    [LayoutRenderer("splitmessage")]
    public class SplitMessageRenderer : LayoutRenderer
    {
        protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            var message = logEvent.FormattedMessage;

            if (message.Length >= 638)
            {
                builder.Append(message);
                return;
            }

            var chunks = SplitIntoChunks(message, 638);
            foreach (var chunk in chunks)
            {
                if (builder.Length > 0)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine();
                }

                builder.Append(chunk);
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoChunks(string input, int chunkSize)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += chunkSize)
            {
                yield return input.Substring(i, Math.Min(chunkSize, input.Length - i));
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
            var blobStorageTargetName = "AzureBlobStorage";

            LayoutRenderer.Register<SplitMessageRenderer>("splitmessage"); 

            var blobStorageTarget = new BlobStorageTarget
            {
                Name = blobStorageTargetName,
                ConnectionString = "<storage-connec-string>",
                Container = "<container-name>",
                BlobName = "<blob-name>",
                Layout = "${longdate} ${level} ${splitmessage:maxSize=638}${newline}"
            };

            config.AddTarget(blobStorageTarget);

            var rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, blobStorageTarget);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

            LogManager.Configuration = config;
            var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

            logger.Error("now we will soon log the longer String");
            string myString = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 639).Select(i => $"a"));

            logger.Error(myString);

            logger.Trace($"Trace msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");
            logger.Debug($"Debug msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");
            logger.Info($"Info msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");
            logger.Warn($"Warn msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");
            logger.Error($"Error msg at {DateTime.UtcNow:O}");

            LogManager.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

The blob uploaded successfully and I can see the blob size as below,

[image]

The blob generated with the message looks like below,

[image]

Comment: Just curious. Is there a real limit for how long a single line can be when using Blob-Storage, which requires explicit newline ? Do Microsoft have some documentation of this behavior/limit ? It sounds really weird with such a limit, as it would make it hard to write Json-Documents that are new-line-delimited.